# Show/Hide elements of a parent form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I have a form submission button that is not visible until a user checks a check box to say that they are human (It's not best practice I know but I don't have enough control to put a Captcha in).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-5 columns large-centered center" 
         id="txtHuman" style="display:none">
    <input class="button" name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Vote now!" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="large-3 columns large-centered verification">
        <label for="isHumanSelected"><span></span></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="isHumanSelected" style="margin-left:-9999px"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
$('#isHumanSelected').click(function() {
    $("#txtHuman").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

That works. But I'd like to hide the checkbox and label used to determine if a user is human or not when the form submission button is visible.

How would I do that?

Comment: Apologies. Forgot to add that. Edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.parent()` to hide those elements, try this:

```
$('#isHumanSelected').click(function() {
    $("#txtHuman").toggle(this.checked);
    $(this).parent('.verification').hide();
});
```

The **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwsus/3/)**

Comment: Np mate glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="PLACEANIDHERE" class="row">

  <div class="large-3 columns large-centered verification">
    <label for="isHumanSelected"><span></span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="isHumanSelected" style="margin-left:-9999px"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Toggle the id of the container. Both the label and checkbox will be visible/hidden at the same time.

Note: Hidding a checkbox won't prevent bots submitting your form... They recreate the form submit, they don't actually fill in the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtHuman").is(":checked"))
    $("#element").hide();
else
alert("not:Checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5rbs6/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#isHumanSelected").on("click",function() {
    $(this).parent().html($("#txtHuman").html());
  });
});
```

Comment: This one made the right things appear and disappear but actually broke the form some how. Not sure what happened.

Comment: Depends on what is IN the parent div. I used your html